# Android with Eclipse: error "GC overhead limit access" with the library google_play_service

Tags: android, eclipse, out-of-memory, google-play-services

i have some problem with Eclipse: it does not load the project on my phone / avd, the error is "GC overhead limit access", I tried to increase the memory of eclipse (from 256 to 1024) but the error persists, this always happens when I load the library google_play_service. What can I do? Thank you ﻿

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open you eclipse properties file and increase the file size as below.

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
```

Comment: as I said, I've already increased the memory in the eclipse.ini file,(from 256 to 1024) but this solution still does not work. Any other suggestions? Thank you